# /etc/sudoers: all commands?

Tags: sudo

I would like user a to run be allowed to run all commands as user b. Unfortunately adding
`a ALL=(b) NOPASSWD: /`
to /etc/sudoers via visudo just yields into syntax errors.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
a ALL=(b) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

`A` can, on `ALL` hosts, as user `B`, without needing to enter a password, run `ALL` commands

Comment: Close... The syntax is correct, but the actual meaning is: A can run the following commands on host "ALL(1)" as user B.  The commands are "ALL(2)" with no password.